# What's the minimum and maximum value of the query field boost weight by default?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

What's the minimum and maximum value for the query boost parameter? I can't find it anywhere in the ES docs.

Also, can the boost parameter be a double like 2.2? or 2.22?

This is how my query looks like:

```
response = await ElasticClient.SearchAsync<Product>(s => s
     .From(skip)
     .Size(productSearch.ItemsPerPage)
     .Index(productSearch.Company + PartOfIndexName + productSearch.Country)
     .Query(q => q
           .QueryString(qs => qs
               .Fields(fs => fs
               .Field(f => f.IdPart1, 4.00)
               .Field(f => f.Title, 3.50)
               .Field(f => f.BrandName, 3.00)
               .Field(f => f.Description, 2.00)
               )
               .Query("*" + productSearch.Query + "*")
              )
            )
      );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the boost can be a float value.

Hence, the max boost you can give is `Float.MAX_VALUE`

Comment: Are you sure that it's float max. value and not double? The datatype says double here. But anyway, I just wanted to know if the number can be any number which the datatype allows or are there any other restrictions. So I guess that you answered my question well. :)

Comment: Depends which boost. In the source code, you can see some float boost and some double boost variables, but definitely floating point.